# Trouble importing CSV and then exporting with some manipulation

Tags: powershell

I have the following file:

> 2018|CIB_C21_A_1_1_FromRangeAmount|.0000

As you can see, it has no headers. The first column can be ignored.  I need to take the 2nd column and then export but I also need to add (2) additional columns in the export.

The export should look like this:

> Account,Parent,Data Storage
>
> CIB_C21_A_1_1|CIB_C21_A|Never Share

As you can see, I need to take the first column and also use the first 9 chracters as a value for another column.  Then I need to add another column with the same value at all times.

I have been trying to play around with this some of this logic but can't quote any anything to work...

```
Import-Csv -Path "C:\TEMPCT\Revenue_RebatesDataForPlanning.csv" -Header zz,Account -Delim "|" |
sort "Account" –Unique | 
Select "Account", "Parent" | 
Export-Csv -Path "C:\TEMPCT\Revenue_RebatesDataForPlanningzz.csv" -Force -NoTypeInformation
```

Could anyone recommend some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use calculated properties with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) to create the desired new columns. To get the 9 first characters of the value from "Account" column you can use the [String.Substring Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0).

```
# This would be:
# Import-Csv path/to/csv.csv -Header Ignore, Account -Delimiter '|' | ... 
@'
2018|CIB_C21_A_1_1_FromRangeAmount|.0000
2018|CIB_C22_A_1_1_FromRangeAmount|.0000
2018|CIB_C23_A_1_1_FromRangeAmount|.0000
2018|CIB_C24_A_1_1_FromRangeAmount|.0000
2018|CIB_C25_A_1_1_FromRangeAmount|.0000
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Ignore, Account -Delimiter '|' |
Select-Object Account, @{
    Name = 'Parent'
    Expression = { $_.Account.Substring(0,9) }
}, @{
    Name = 'Data Storage'
    Expression = { 'Never Share' }
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

How your code should look:

```
Import-Csv path/to/csv.csv -Header Ignore, Account -Delimiter '|' |
Select-Object Account, @{
    Name = 'Parent'
    Expression = { $_.Account.Substring(0,9) }
}, @{
    Name = 'Data Storage'
    Expression = { 'Never Share' }
} | Export-Csv path/to/newCsv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you, Santiago!  I am getting the expected results within the console! However, when I need to export, the Account and Parent columns are blank. Here is what I"ve tried. Where am I going wrong?

`Import-Csv "C:\TEMPCT\Revenue_RebatesDataForPlanning.csv" -Header Ignore, Account -Delimiter '|' |
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Ignore, Account -Delimiter '|' |
Select-Object Account, 
@{Name = 'Parent';Expression = { $_.Account.SubString(0,9) }}, 
@{Name = 'Data Storage';Expression = { 'Never Share' }} | 
Export-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Path "C:\TEMPCT\zz.csv" -Force -NoTypeInformation
`

Comment: @SIMMS7400 `| ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Ignore, Account -Delimiter '|'` shouldn't be there :) It's in my answer just for displaying how it works however since you're doing it from a file you don't needed

Comment: @SIMMS7400 see my last edit

Comment: Thank you, Santiago!  That worked perfectly!!!  I actually need to add another level to the file, so what I did was create another piece of logic but wondering if I can combine these?
Essentially, the value in the parent columns needs to be first added to the Account column and the Parent column of that is always hard coded to 'Rebate Tables' but this Data Storage value is 'Label Only'
Here is the file format:
```Account|Parent|Data Storage
CIB_C21_A|Rebate_Tables|Label Only
CIB_C21_A_1_1_FromRangeAmount|CIB_C21_A|Never Share
```

Comment: And here is my logic to get what I need, which works, but i'm sure there's a more efficient way.  First piece of code:
```Import-Csv 'C:\TEMPCT\Revenue_RebatesDataForPlanning.csv' -Header Ignore, Account -Delimiter '|' |
Select-Object @{
    Name = 'Account'
    Expression = { $_.Account.Substring(0,9) }
}, @{
    Name = 'Parent'
    Expression = { 'Rebate_Tables' }
}, @{
    Name = 'Data Storage'
    Expression = { 'Label Only' }
} | 
sort 'Account' –Unique |
Export-Csv 'C:\TEMPCT\Revenue_RebatesDataForPlanning1.csv' -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Second piece of code:
```Import-Csv 'C:\TEMPCT\Revenue_RebatesDataForPlanning.csv' -Header Ignore, Account -Delimiter '|' |
Select-Object Account, @{
    Name = 'Parent'
    Expression = { $_.Account.Substring(0,9) }
}, @{
    Name = 'Data Storage'
    Expression = { 'Never Share' }
} | Export-Csv "C:\TEMPCT\Revenue_RebatesDataForPlanning2.csv" -Delimiter '|' -Force -NoTypeInformation;
Get-Content 'C:\TEMPCT\Revenue_RebatesDataForPlanning2.csv' |
Select-Object -skip 1 |
Out-File 'C:\TEMPCT\Revenue_RebatesDataForPlanning3.csv'
```

Comment: Final piece 
```Get-Content 'C:\TEMPCT\Revenue_RebatesDataForPlanning1.csv', 'C:\TEMPCT\Revenue_RebatesDataForPlanning3.csv'|
ForEach-Object {$_.replace('"','')} |
Out-File 'C:\TEMPCT\COmbined.csv'
```

Comment: @SIMMS7400 please, if this answered your initial question consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) and ask a new question with all these new details.